# Как установить фиксированный размер изображения, которое является фоном кнопки

Tags: android, android-button

Не могу понять, как сделать изображение фиксированным 24dp по высоте и ширине, так чтобы сама кнопка была 48dp по высоте и ширине. В качестве изображений использую SVG. `android:padding...` на кнопке не помогает.

Кнопка:

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_more_vert_black"/>
```

Фон:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_more_vert_black_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_more_vert_black_default"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_more_vert_black_default" />
</selector>
```

btn_more_vert_black_default - стандартные иконки из библиотеки материального дизайна.

Comment: Паддинг на фон не работает. В случае кнопки он сработает на текст на ней. Попробуйте заменить кнопку на ImageView и программно менять изображение. Или в xml создать фон, в котором задать паддинг и поставить ваш svg в виде bitmap

Comment: Спасибо! Все сработало. Использую ImageButton и программно ставлю изображение.

Answer (score 2):

1. Использую ImageButton:

   ```
   <ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/btn"
   android:layout_width="48dp"
   android:layout_height="48dp"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
   ```
2. Программно устанавливаю изображение:

   ```
   ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn)).setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_more_vert_black);
   ```

Где `btn_more_vert_black` картинка в svg с размерами 24dp на 24dp